# How can I make a django model upload its files to a folder named after the model instance?

Tags: python, django

How can I make a django model upload its files to a folder named after a property of the models instance?

Here is my model. I am trying to make it upload all files to badgeTemplates/[model instance name here].

```
class BadgeTemplate(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
template = models.FileField(upload_to='badgeTemplates/',unique=True)
configFile = models.FileField(upload_to='badgeTemplates/',unique=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I've tried `upload_to='badgeTemplates/' + self.name` but it says that self isn't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callable to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
class BadgeTemplate(models.Model):
    
    def upload_file_name(self, filename):
        return f'badgeTemplates/{self.name}/{filename}'
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    template = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_file_name, unique=True)
    configFile = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_file_name, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You should *not* use parenthesis (<s>`upload_file_name()`</s>), since then you pass the *result* of the function call. You need to pass a reference to the function itself.

Comment: if I do this 'def upload_file_name(self, filename): #sets upload location to badgeTemplates/self.name/
        return f'badgeTemplates/{self.name}/template/{filename}', how can I delete the self.name folder when the model instance is deleted?

Comment: @memtech3: you can make a signal, or a management command for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19288242/67579

Comment: what does the if instance.pk statement do?

Comment: @memtech3: it obtain the id (primary key) of the instance before it is saved.

Comment: @memtech3: perhaps you can take a look at some Django plugins for that: https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup and https://github.com/akolpakov/django-unused-media

Comment: '@receiver(pre_delete, sender=BadgeTemplate)
def delete_orphaned_template_files(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    shutil.rmtree('badgeTemplates/'+instance.name+'/')' do you see any problems with this?